# Spring 3: map page.html to page.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3 and i don't know how to map somepage.htm to somepage.jsp without a controller.
That is: if i go to somepage.htm, i want it to show me the jsp. But of course without redirect. I dontw want anyone to see ".jsp" only ".htm"

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Training01</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Training01</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do is to use the `<mvc:view-controller..>` tag in combination with a view resolver.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-controller) for more documentation:

The `<mvc:view-controller..>` tag maps urls to views. So if you want to map the relative url `/login` to a view names login you would do it by adding the following line to you `webmvc-context.xml` file:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />
```

Of course to get this to work you'll have to have a view resolve - something that maps logic names to specific views - setup in your context. In your case since you are using straight jsps for you view layer you'll want to add something like this to your configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

So with this setup if you had a jsp login.jsp located in you `/WEB-INF/jsp` directory then you would be able to directly reference that jsp from the url `www.myapp.com/mycontenxtroot/login`

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-resolver) for some more info on view resolvers:

Comment: Ah, yes, the "add more XML" approach. ;)

Comment: Yea, spring and xml go together like peanut butter and chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). This is the approach I would recommend. If you're serious about clean URLs you'll likely need it at some point anyway.

On the other hand, if it's a one-off, a minimal controller might be easier:

```
@Controller
public class Somepage {
    @RequestMapping("/somepage")
    public String handler() {
        return "somepage.jsp";
    }
}
```